# how to configure webhook activity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I wonder what the webhook activity used for. this is my first webhook activity ,configured as below screenshot it failed when I debug this activity as below, if I want to update key vault through this activity, what should I configure?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alex Wang, you need add more details to clarify your issue and what you have tried and the posts you followed.

Comment: Are you trying to update Key Vault? If so a Web activity should do it. Or are you trying to learn how to use a Webhook activity for more academic reasons?

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to use a Webhook activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find webhook activity configure details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/automation/automation-webhooks).